# crackme binary crashing on Raspberry pi

Tags: arm, crackme

I was trying out a basic ARM crackme [here](http://crackmes.cf/users/blankwall/arm_crack1/). Upon running it on my Raspberry pi, it segfaults without giving me any warning. Moreover, I'm unable to set breakpoints anywhere(even on the entry point). Is there some gdb/ARM quirk that I should be aware of? This has happened on an earlier occasion too with another CTF challenge.

I do get the feeling that my questions is incomplete -- however, I'm not sure what additional information I could provide to help diagnose the problem. If you could let me know what additional information is required, I could update the question with that.

Some output :-

```
$ file arm_crack1
arm_crack1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, BuildID[sha1]=0xbb39a930c55e6d62c7cc083bb94567adcfe5cc3b, stripped
$ ldd arm_crack1
    not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: Could you also include a ldd dump? Might be interesting to see how everything gets linked together on the target system. I haven't tried taking a look at the binary to see if there is any dependencies. If it doesn't depend on any libraries it's probably doing syscalls directly which can change between kernel versions.

Comment: have you tried running strace on it? What kernel version are you running on the RPi?